# OrientDB auto creation of vertex/edge schema classes

Tags: orientdb

As far as I can tell there is no way to specify that an existing schema class should be used when a matching label is specified but default to the general V/E classes otherwise. I have few custom E sub classes that I would like to use but I don't want other edge labels to cause the creation of additional sub classes. The API I'm using is TinkerPop-based and I cannot  explicitly specify vertex/edge classes.

The OrientConfigurableGraph.setUseClassForEdgeLabel(boolean) setting is an all or nothing option. If it is set to true schema classes are created for all labels and if it is set to false new vertex/edge instances are set to the general V/E classes even if there is a matching class. Am I correct about this? I would like a configuration option that allows the use of matching schema classes if they are available in the schema but without automatically creating others when there is no match. I'm using version 2.1.8.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing the OrientDB v2.1.x reference documentation and javadocs, i couldn't find a configuration option that configures the graph the way you want, so what you can do, is to open a ticket in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues) at github and request that feature.

Although, in the meantime, you can control this programatically with the Graph API with the custom vertex/edges functions, as explained in the [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Graph-Schema.html), not ideal, as you need to control this programatically, but for now is the closest i could find.